# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity while executing Retrofit GET method in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

I am new to Android application development .I have looked into some of the online tutorials and wiki's and started developing application which will be calling the API's hosted on Apache server (PHP+SLIM+MySQL)..I have created some of the API's and tested them successfully with RESTClient for Chrome.

For android , after some research, i have decided to use Square's retrofit library which seems to work very efficiently(5-6 time faster then Apache.http protocol implemented in Android and 2-3 times faster then Volley(Google) and Robospice) and very light memory footprint.

I have created a sample Android project (using Android studio 0.8 beta) and implemented Rertofit by following their documentation. but when i have compiled my project and burned my apk to my phone...it is failing to execute with "java.lang.IllegalStateException" .following is the details of my implementation of the same..

I am not sure how to rectify this error ...am i missing anything in manifestfile or not implementing any method which i am supposed to implement...

**Library(including all gradle dependencies) i am including**

- Gson 2.3
- retrofit 1.6.1
- okhttp 2.0
- okhttp-urlconnection 2.0
- okio 1.0.1

**Structure**

```
public class MyStructures {
                  public static class Contributor {
                    public String login;
                    public int contributions;
                  }
               }
```

**Interface**

```
  public interface MyInterface {

            @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
            List<Contributor> contributors(
                    @Path("owner") String owner,
                    @Path("repo") String repo
            );
        }
```

**Adapter Creation ,call to REST method, Result fetching**

```
private static final String API_URL = "https://api.github.com";    
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                        .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                        .build();

                // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
                MyInterface myInterface = restAdapter.create(MyInterface.class);


                // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to this library.
                List<Contributor> contributors = myInterface.contributors("square", "retrofit");
                for (Contributor contributor : contributors) {
                  System.out.println(contributor.login + " (" + contributor.contributions + ")");

               }
```

**Manifest file :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication" >
    <!-- added this two permission by looking in to some answer on stackoverflow 
    which i geuss not required for newer android version since googles has given n/w permission by default-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please provide full details on the exception you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

My first time having this problem is solved by adding following permission into the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```